# (Autohotkey Excel) Want to check if current Cell value is " Beef Jerky", then goto LabelA, if Empty (" ") goto LabelB

Tags: autohotkey

Hello i need help for my Excel automation using autohotkey..

So I just want to check if current cell value is " Beef Jerky", then goto LabelA. , if current cell value is empty ( " " ), then goto LabelB.

it's simple but i couldnt figure it out yet on how to write in in line of autohotkey code, can somebody help me with this? Thankyou very much

Comment: Did you you try anything yet? You could either send some hotkey to copy the contents of the current cell (`Ctrl` + `v` for example?), or you could do it the fancy/proper way and [connect to excel via COM](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/69033-basic-ahk-l-com-tutorial-for-excel/).

Comment: okay THankyou verymuch for your help!